# Access template (class) arguments outside the template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to access functions of a class template argument outside the template? I tried the following without success:

```
class A  {
public:
    void func () { std::cout << ("A called"); }
};

template<class T>
class tClass {
public:
    T* operator->() {
        return mem;
    }

    T* operator*() {
        return mem;
    }

    const T* operator->() const {
        return mem;
    }

    const T* operator*() const {
        return mem;
    }

private:
    T* mem;
};
```

and in main:

```
tClass<A>* t = new tClass<A>();
t->func();
```

I get the following compiler error: `error: 'class tClass<A>' has no member named 'func'`
Doesn't overriding the `->` operator return a pointer to the template argument? I'm asking because I've seen a very similar code that was working. I've also seen other answers suggesting using `typedef`, but I'm not sure how it applies here.

Ignore the fact that the `mem` object is not initialized now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably meant `(*t)->func();`

Comment: Also, following smart pointers' interface [operator->](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operator->/) should return a pointer while [operator*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operator-%3E/) should return a reference. But of course you can implement them however you want, just pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
tClass<A>* t = new tClass<A>();
t->func();
```

isn't calling `tClass<A>::operator->`, it's dereferencing the `tClass<A>*` itself. And `tClass<A>` doesn't have a `func()` member function, hence the error. You would have to either double dereference:

```
(*t)->func();
```

Or use a non-pointer to `tClass<A>`:

```
tClass<A> t;
t->func();
```

---

Side-note, this phrasing:

> return a pointer to the template argument

isn't right. The template argument is a *type*. In this case, `A`. You're returning a pointer to something which has that type - not the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to initialize your pointer T* mem!, e.g.

```
template<class T>
class tClass {
public:
    explicit tClass(T *p):mem(p){}

    T* operator->() {
        return mem;
    }

    T* operator*() {
        return mem;
    }

    const T* operator->() const {
        return mem;
    }

    const T* operator*() const {
        return mem;
    }

private:
    T* mem;
};
```

and then

```
tClass<A> t(new A() );
```

and then go on.

Comment: `Ignore the fact that the mem object is not initialized now.` I think the op is aware of that.